# R: Permutations and check the position of each value within a given permutation. Converting Mathematica to R

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, permutation, random

so below I have some mathematica code and I would like to know how to do this in R. For those not familiar with mathematica I will explain what this code does.

We are looking at the permutations of the list (1,2,3,4).

We generate a list of these permutations: {(1,2,3,4),(1,2,4,3)...etc}.

Then for each permutation, we check to see how many of the elements are in the right spot. E.g. if the current permutation is (4,2,3,1) then 2 and 3 are both in the correct spot and I want to recode this as the value 2, (1,4,2,3) would be 1, etc

then I want to randomly sample 1000000 times from these recoded list.

I know in R this last part is in the form of

```
sample(vectorToSample,10^6,replace=True)
```

Here it the mathematica code

```
RandomChoice[
  Table[
    Total[
     Table[Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}][[i]][[j]] == j, {j, 1,4}]
    ]
  , {i, 1,24}]/. {True -> 1,False -> 0}
, 10^6]
```

Or in a much cleaner way

```
RandomChoice[{9/24, 8/24, 6/24, 1/24} -> {0, 1, 2, 4}, 10^6]
```

Comment: I know the question is about a R version but here is a more efficient code for counting number of derangements in permutations in Mathematica :  Tally[Map[ Count[#-Range[4],0 ]&,Permutations[Range[4]]]]

Comment: @ogerard I really appreciate the more efficient coding of this. Could you walk me through the pure function you have?

Comment: The pure function in the Map statement is just subtracting the current permutation (# = first argument of the function, supplied by map) from the list to the identity permutation ({1,2,3,4}=Range[4]) and then counting zeros : the number of fixed points. This way you don't need to use indices such as i and j in your code.  Tally then produce a list of (values, count of occurrences in the form {{val1,count1},{val2,count2},...} that you can sort and convert to fractions if you want)

Comment: @ogerard, that is so cleaver. I like it!